# How to edit ol tags in rich text editor

Tags: css, angularjs, html, textangular

I am creating and ordered list using [Text Angular](http://textangular.com/) and able to create orderlist which starts with 1,2,3 by default. Text angular has 2 modes
**1. Rich Text mode
 1. HTML mode**

**HTML mode shows**

```
 <ol>
       <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
 </ol>
```

**Rich Text mode will show as:**

1. test
2. test

If I need to start ordered list with number 5, I need to switch to **HTML mode**  ***first*** and do the below change

```
<ol start="5">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

Now the **Rich Text mode** starts the numbering with 5

5. test
6. test

The real problem is how to change the numbering by clicking on the pseudo element generated by the < ol> tag **while on the rich text editor mode.** After googling and research it seems the  pseudo element cannot be changed.

**Stack overflow editor** gives the option of changing this in **Rich Text mode itself!**

So while adding the below data in **Rich Text mode** starting with 4 for example

```
 4. number 4
 3. number 3
```

The **preview** mode ends up displaying **buggy** result.

4. number 4
5. number 3

if you noticed `5. number 3`. this was generated from the Rich text editor.

There are JS way to replace  tags in the DOM and give a simlar  tag look n feel using combination of html tags etc which I am not looking for at this point.

Would there be a creative CSS way to change the number on the fly in the **rich text mode** (rather than doing **html mode**) in Text Angular.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "selected"?

Comment: The desired functionality in the way you're asking for it is not possible. You can neither select and copy/paste the ordinal pseudo element that's generated by the ordered list, nor can you use CSS alone to add the copy/paste context menu behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution is  inspired by S.Klechkovski's answer. On the editor type a number, say **5** , select the number, click on on ol tag in TextAngular, the old now starts with **5**

The difference is in `var startingNumber = parseInt($(taSelection.getSelectionElement()).text());`

```
$provide.decorator('taTools', function ($delegate, $document, taSelection) {

      // NOTE: override the ol action
      var olAction = $delegate.ol.action;
      $delegate.ol.action = function () {

        if (!this.active) {
          // NOTE: replace with better way for integrating the feature
        var startingNumber = parseInt($(taSelection.getSelectionElement()).text());

          // do the ordering
          var result = olAction.apply(this, arguments);

          // change the starting number
          var element = angular.element(taSelection.getSelection().start.element);
          var parentOls = element.parents('ol');
          if (parentOls.length > 0) {
            angular.element(parentOls[0]).attr('start', startingNumber); 
          }

          // clean up
          element = null;
          parentOl = null;
          return result;
        } else {
          return olAction.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      };

      return $delegate;
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

As I understood, what you need is a feature for changing the starting number when using the ordered list which is not implemented by the *text-angular* editor at the moment. What *text-angular* provides you in such cases is easy extending of the toolbar by adding new or overriding existing functionalities.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eHWiNOnRi5fJPtnGwt8Y?p=preview) with an example implementation of the feature you need. I have implemented it by overriding the *ol* button configuration like this:

```
app.decorator('taTools', function ($delegate, $document, taSelection) {

  // NOTE: override the ol action
  var olAction = $delegate.ol.action;
  $delegate.ol.action = function () {

    if (!this.active) {
      // NOTE: replace with better way for integrating the feature
      var startingNumber = $document.find('#startingNumber').val();

      // do the ordering
      var result = olAction.apply(this, arguments);

      // change the starting number
      var element = angular.element(taSelection.getSelection().start.element);
      var parentOls = element.parents('ol');
      if (parentOls.length > 0) {
        angular.element(parentOls[0]).attr('start', startingNumber); 
      }

      // clean up
      element = null;
      parentOl = null;
      return result;
    } else {
      return olAction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };

  return $delegate;
});
```

The way for configuring the starting number IMO is not so good, it's just for showcase because replacing it with better way takes more effort (ex. dropdown on the *ol* button). You can replace it with what is most convenient for you.

For more information and examples on Text-Angular editor you can check its [documentation](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki) and the [page](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar) for customizing the toolbar.

Comment: Nice effort! Have you tried Stack Overflow editor for editing ol tags.? Would like something similar for text angular. also i would like to avoid ('#startingNumber').val() approach if possible

Comment: Thanks, I am glad that you liked it. I hope that you got the idea how you can implement extensions for this great component. To implement what you need it's not so trivial and takes some time. You can create an issue/feature request on their GitHub repo. or try to implement it by your self. Cheers!

Comment: @faiz, you didn't write any feedback. It would be helpful for others to see how you solved this.

Comment: added the answer - inspired by your answer :)

Comment: And why it's still not accepted? You think you can get better answer?

Comment: have added the below answer. However, the points will be distributed within a day

Comment: If you don't add them manually then only half of them will be given automatically by the system, the other half is waisted.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** After the question was edited my answer no longer fits very well. Since it still received upvotes afterwards I'm going to assume that it was nonetheless helpful and just leave it here.

As has been mentioned in comments and other answers, the clicking part is not possible. It is possible to highlight the numbering.

Add a custom counter in the `:before` part of your `<li>` tags and have them react to hovering:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: my-counter;
}

ol > li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: my-counter;
    content: counter(my-counter) '. ';
}

ol > li:hover:before {
    color: red;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/u1uhr7s8/

Again, it is not possible to add anything clickable in place of the numbers because the `before:` bit does not truly become part of the DOM.

Comment: @faiz: I feel like my answer no longer fits your question after you edited it, but since it's received some upvotes I'm going to leave it here in case other people find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

'selected' here could mean a number of different things.  You'll need to clarify your question to get the answers you're after, but if you're looking to reference this in Javascript somewhere, you can use any of the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ol') //Will return a list of all OLs on the page
document.querySelectorAll('ol') //Will return a list of all OLs on the page
$('ol') //Will return a list of all OLs on the page, but requires JQuery
```

To get the '1' or '2' li elements, you'd include the LI within the query, or select it as a child of what's returned:

```
var myOL = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];
var myItems = myOL.children;
```

or with JQuery

```
var myItems = $('ol li');
```

If you're talking about targeting the OL with CSS rules, you just use the tag name, e.g.

```
ol {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

and again, if you're after the LIs you can either target them all:

```
ol li {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

or target a specific child using nth-child:

```
ol li:nth-child(2) { /* second child - '2' in your case */
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```